# Using WHERE clause to find POI within a range of distance from Longitude and Latitude

Tags: mysql, sql, gps, geometry, geo

I'm using following sql code to find out 'ALL' poi closest to the set coordinates, but I would want to find out specific poi instead of all of them. When I try to use the where clause I get an error and it doesn't work and this is where I'm currently stuck, since I only use one table for all the coordinates off all poi's.

```
SET @orig_lat=55.4058;  
SET @orig_lon=13.7907; 
SET @dist=10;
SELECT 
    *, 
    3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -abs(latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
    + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(latitude) * pi()/180) 
    * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance 
FROM geo_kulplex.sweden_bobo
HAVING distance < @dist 
ORDER BY distance limit 10;
```

Comment: Doesnt work how? Can you paste an error message in your question?

Comment: to optimize speed/performance of such query read this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5749614/43959

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that you can not reference an aliased column (`distance`in this case) in a `select` or `where` clause. For example, you can't do this:

```
select a, b, a + b as NewCol, NewCol + 1 as AnotherCol from table
where NewCol = 2
```

This will fail in both: the `select` statement when trying to process `NewCol + 1` and also in the `where` statement when trying to process `NewCol = 2`.

There are two ways to solve this:

1) Replace the reference by the calculated value itself. Example:

```
select a, b, a + b as NewCol, a + b + 1 as AnotherCol from table
where  a + b = 2
```

2) Use an outer `select` statement:

```
select a, b, NewCol, NewCol + 1 as AnotherCol from (
    select a, b, a + b as NewCol from table
) as S
where NewCol = 2
```

Now, given your HUGE and not very human-friendly calculated column :) I think you should go for the last option to improve readibility:

```
SET @orig_lat=55.4058;  
SET @orig_lon=13.7907; 
SET @dist=10;

SELECT * FROM (
  SELECT 
    *, 
    3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -abs(latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) 
    + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(latitude) * pi()/180) 
    * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance 
  FROM geo_kulplex.sweden_bobo
) AS S
WHERE distance < @dist
ORDER BY distance limit 10;
```

**Edit:** As @Kaii mentioned below this will result in a full table scan. Depending on the amount of data you will be processing you might want to avoid that and go for the first option, which should perform faster.

Comment: You should mention that this always requires a FULL TABLE SCAN and may perform bad on huge datasets

Comment: posted my own answer to point that out more clearly. Either of your solutions will perform equally bad. No index can be used for such a complicated calculation.

Comment: I've figured it out and i went for the faster perfomance, thanks for your support.

Answer (score 4):

The reason why you cant use your alias in the `WHERE` clause is the order in which MySQL executes things:

1. `FROM`
2. `WHERE`
3. `GROUP BY`
4. `HAVING`
5. `SELECT`
6. `ORDER BY`

When executing your `WHERE` clause, the value for your column alias is not yet calculated. This is a good thing, because it would waste a lot of performance. Imagine many (1,000,000) rows -- to use your calculation in the `WHERE` clause, each of those 1,000,000 would first have to be fetched and calculated so the `WHERE` condition can compare the calculation results to your expectation.

You can do this explicitly by either

- using `HAVING` (thats the reason why `HAVING` has another name as `WHERE` - its a different thing)
- using a subquery as illustrated by @MostyMostacho (will effectively do the same with some overhead)
- put the complex calculation in the `WHERE` clause (will effectively give the same performance result as `HAVING`)

**All those will perform almost equally bad: each row is fetched first, the distance calculated and finally filtered by distance before sending the result to the client.**

You can gain much (!) better performance by mixing a simple `WHERE` clause for distance approximation (filtering rows to fetch first) with the more precise euclidian formula in a `HAVING` clause.

1. find rows that *could* match the `@distance = 10` condition using a `WHERE` clause based on simple X and Y distance (bounding box) -- this is a *cheap* operation.
2. filter those results using the formula for euclidian distance in a `HAVING` clause -- this is an *expensive* operation.

Look at this query to understand what i mean:

```
SET @orig_lat=55.4058;
SET @orig_lon=13.7907; 
SET @dist=10;
SELECT 
    *, 
    3956 * 2 * ASIN(SQRT(POWER(SIN((@orig_lat -abs(latitude)) * pi()/180 / 2), 2)
    + COS(@orig_lat * pi()/180 ) * COS(abs(latitude) * pi()/180) 
    * POWER(SIN((@orig_lon - longitude) * pi()/180 / 2), 2) )) as distance 
FROM geo_kulplex.sweden_bobo
/* WHERE clause to pre-filter by distance approximation .. filter results 
   later with precise euclidian calculation. can use indexes. */
WHERE 
    /* i'm unsure about geo stuff ... i dont think you want a 
       distance of 10° here, please adjust this properly!! */
    latitude BETWEEN (@orig_lat - @dist) AND (@orig_lat + @dist)
    AND longitude BETWEEN (@orig_lon - @dist) AND (@orig_lon + @dist)
/* HAVING clause to filter result using the more precise euclidian distance */
HAVING distance < @dist 
ORDER BY distance limit 10;
```

For those who are interested in the constant:

- 3956 is the radius of the earth in miles, so the resulting distance is measured in miles
- 6371 is the radius of the earth in kilometers, so use this constant to measure distance in kilometers

Find more information in the [wiki about the Haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula)

Comment: @HenryDang Glad to hear i could help you. If you like the answer click on the check mark left to accept it :-)