# Misuse of aggregate in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, group-by, aggregate-functions, having-clause

This error occurs in this `SQLite` query:

```
select f.rid, c.title, sum(some_expression) as ratio
from doesntmatter
where c.active = 1 or (ratio = 1.0 and c.active = 0
      and c.deactivated in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
group by f.rid
```

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/648083/sql-error-misuse-of-aggregate) question solves it with `having` clause:

```
select f.rid, c.title, sum(some_expression) as ratio
from doesntmatter
where c.active = 1 or (c.active = 0
      and c.deactivated in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)
group by f.rid
having ratio = 1.0
```

But in my case this changes the semantics of the expression. Do you know how to achieve the expression that is in the original `where` clause?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Basically, you can't reference an aliased column in a where clause. Take a look at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9453652) to see how to workaround that.

Aditionally, you should add to the group by all non-aggregated columns present in the `select` statement, in this case, `c.id` and `c.title`.

It is difficult to rewrite that query for you because the logic is a bit difficult to understand (because of the wrong group by).

**Edit:**

After a second thought, you might just need to correct the `group by`.

```
select c.id, c.title, sum(some_expression) as ratio
from doesntmatter
where c.active = 1 or (c.active = 0 and c.deactivated in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
group by c.id, c.title
having ratio = 1.0
```

Or maybe:

```
select f.rid, sum(some_expression) as ratio
from doesntmatter
where c.active = 1 or (c.active = 0 and c.deactivated in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5))
group by f.rid
having ratio = 1.0
```

I can't help you with the previous part because I don't know the fields nor the data of your tables nor how to interpret them. But selecting fields not present in the group by is a bad idea. Anyway, remember you can always join back to the original tables and get the info you are looking for, not just the fields displayed in the `select`.

Comment: I tried it but it's impossible to move `sum(some_expression)` to `where clause` because there are two aggregate functions - `sum` and `count`

Comment: Is it possible to create nested queries? The inner query would create a table (id, title, active, deactivated, ratio) and the outer query would select only rows satisfying `where c.active = 1 or (ratio = 1.0 and c.active = 0 and c.deactivated in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5)`. But I don't know how to reference the columns in the outer query...

Comment: I noticed that you're solving the nested statement in the other question. I was only afraid of `MySQL`.

Comment: `group by` is OK. There are two joined tables. I will try it with `nested query` but it seems that I have only the possibility for `full scan` as you wrote in another question.

Comment: I've updated the question. Maybe it just requires a correction on the group by. If this still requires more processing then a subquery might be used. Note: The group by is not right

Comment: OK, the second one is right (this was my another mistake). Now, I'm thinking using the `union` statement, it seems that in that case I can already use the `having clause` in one of the statements.

Comment: It seems that the `union` of two tables works great. ((f.rid, ratio) where active = 1) union ((f.rid, ratio) where (active = 0 and deactivated in (1, 2, 3, 4, 5) having ratio = 1.0) . I haven't tried nested queries (too complex for me :-) )